# Relationship between tables (hasOne) Object of class ... could not be converted to string

Tags: cakephp-3.x, has-one

I have 2 tables one of images that belong to several different tables and in the other table the reference for id_imagen with the id of the table images.

Table Documentos:

> id | id_imagen | titulo | texto

Table Imagenes:

> id | tabla | imagen | tipo

Relationship:

> Doumentos.id_imagen = Imagenes.id

In the model of images I have put:

```
$this->belongsTo('Escudos', [
          'className' => 'Documentos',
          'foreignKey' => 'id_imagen',
          'conditions' => ['tabla' => 'escudos']
        ]);
```

In the model of documentos I have put:

```
$this->hasOne('Imagenes');
```

In the documentos controller:

```
$imagenes = TableRegistry::get('Imagenes');
$documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');

$documentos = $imagenes->$documentos
                        ->find('all')
                        ->select(['Documentos.id', 'Documentos.titulo', 'Documentos.texto', 'Imagenes.imagen'])
                        ->all();
$this->set('documentos', $documentos);
```

I get the following error:

> Warning (4096): Object of class App\Model\Table\DocumentosTable could not
>   be converted to string [APP/Controller/DocumentosController.php, line 21]

Comment: You forgot to put an actual question into your question.

Comment: think it's obvious what I'm asking, it's not working and I want to know what I'm doing wrong. regards

Comment: In the question I added the error that gives me

Comment: It's not obvious to anyone what exactly isn't working. Please remember that nobody here knows what exactly is happening with your code if you don't tell. And while I can see various problems in your code, problems should be reproducible not only so that they can be easily answered, but also so that other people that aren't yet overly familiar with CakePHP can learn from it. Your update for example shows that the error you are experiencing has nothing to do with the (wrongly setup) associations.

Answer (score 1):

Look at what you are doing in line `21`:

```
$imagenes->$documentos
```

You are passing `$documentos` as the propery name to access on `$imagenes`, that's of course not going to work, as `$documents` is an object, as the error message suggests.

The `documentos` variable shouldn't be there in the first place. You want to query on `$imagenes`:

```
$imagenes->find()->/* ... */
```

Besides that your associations are not setup correctly, the `Escudos` association must be `hasOne` (the other table has the foreign key), and the `Imagenes` association must be `belongsTo` (the current table has the foreign key). Also as you are using non-conventional column names, you must at least configure the foreign key for the `Imagenes` association too.

- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations - Linking Tables Together](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html)**

Answer (score 0):

In the end I found the solution:

Documentos table:

```
$this->hasOne('Imagenes')
             ->setBindingKey('id_imagen')
             ->setForeignKey('id');
```

Imagenes table:

```
$this->belongsTo('Documentos')
            ->setForeignKey('id_imagen')
            ->setJoinType('INNER');
```

Documentos Controller:

```
public function Documento() {
    $documentos = TableRegistry::get('Documentos');

    $documentos = $documentos->find('all')
                       ->contain(['Imagenes']);
    $this->set('documentos', $documentos);
  }
```

view:

```
<?= $documento->imagen->imagen; ?>
```